# Does IE7 have a problem applying CSS to dynamically created DOM Elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm building an HTML page that uses endless scrolling functionality to render new list elements as you scroll down, like on Facebook.  I'm using the [jquery.pageless plugin](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless).

The thing is, now testing it on IE7, when I load the dynamic content, none of it is styled like it should be.  The first set (20 rows), which the server generated in the html page, look fine.  Then the next 20-per-page that are rendered with javascript, don't have any of the styles applied.

How do I fix this?  Having a hard time testing it in IE7 from a mac.  Is this a problem with IE7?  Or could perhaps the elements not be being appended to the correct parent div in IE (using jQuery so I doubt this)?  Or is there a common hack for reloading the stylesheets after every dynamically created html element is added?

The doctype is HTML5: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Thanks for the advice!

**Update**:

Looking in the IE7 developer panel, the HTML is being spit out all malformed.  The first time around it looks like this:

```
<article class='community-page page none vevent' data-status='available' data-type='community_page' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Event'>
  <figure class='snapshot'><time class='availability dtstart' datetime='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00' itemprop='startDate' title='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00'><span class='value-title' title='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00'></span></time><a href="/users/25?page_id=25" class="fancy-ajax logo"><span></span><img alt="Logo for Heavenly Cleaning" class="photo" src="/images/41/heavenly-cleaning-logo-small.JPG?1297971958" title="Logo for Heavenly Cleaning" /></a>
    <a href="/pages/25/bookmarks" class="status bookmark">Like</a>
  </figure>
  <section class='details' itemprop='seller' itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization'>
    <header class='header'>
      <hgroup>
        <h3 class='user fn org' itemprop='name'>
          <a href="/users/25?page_id=25" class="fancy-ajax">Name</a><span class='hyphen'>-</span><span class='distance'>Wheaton, IL</span>
        </h3>
        <h2 class='title'><span class='quotation-mark'>"</span><a href="/users/25/pages/25" class="url summary">Quote</a><span class='quotation-mark'>"</span><time class='expiration-date dtend'><span class='value-title' title='2011-12-16T00:00:00-08:00'></span></time></h2>
      </hgroup>
    </header>
    <p class='highlights'></p>
    <p class='description' itemprop='description'></p>
    <footer class='footer'>
      <address class='location adr' itemprop='address' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Address'>
        <span class='locality' itemprop='locality'></span>
        <span class='geo' itemprop='geo' itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Geo'>
          <span class='latitude' itemprop='latitude'>
            <span class='value-title' title='41.850249'></span>
          </span>
          <span class='longitude' itemprop='longitude'>
            <span class='value-title' title='-88.0855459'></span>
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class='tel' itemprop='tel'></span>
      </address>
      Category: <a href="/pages/home" class="category" itemprop="category" rel="tag" target="_top">Home</a>
    </footer>
  </section>
</article>
```

The second time around it looks more like this:

```
<article class='community-page page none vevent' data-status='available' data-type='community_page' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Event'/>
<figure class='snapshot'/>
<time class='availability dtstart' datetime='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00' itemprop='startDate' title='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00'/>
<span class='value-title' title='2010-12-16T00:00:00-08:00'/>
</time/>
<a href="/users/25?page_id=25" class="fancy-ajax logo">
  <span/>
  <img alt="Logo for Heavenly Cleaning" class="photo" src="/images/41/name-logo-small.JPG?1297971958" title="Logo for Heavenly Cleaning" />
</a>
<a href="/pages/25/bookmarks" class="status bookmark">Like</a>
</figure/>
...
```

I am returning it as a json string and appending it like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var params = paginator;
  params.dataType = "string";
  $('#content').pageless({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    params:      params,
    distance:    500,
    totalPages:  10,
    loaderImage: "/images/loaders/load.gif",
    scrape: function(data) {
      var data      = $.parseJSON(data);
      var paginator = data.paginator;
      var search    = data.search;
      var html      = data.pages // html string;

      if (data.more == false) {
        $.pageless.settings.totalPages = $.pageless.settings.currentPage;
        if($.pageless.settings.totalPages <= $.pageless.settings.currentPage){
          $.pageless.stopListener();
        }
      }

      $.pageless.settings.params = {dataType: "string", paginator: paginator, q: search.q, c: search.c, l: search.l, a: search.a};

      return html;
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: IE7 has many problems, but I can't remember anything like that. You probably have some problem that other browsers are handling better. Any chance of a link to a live page? It's *by far* the easiest way to debug these issues.

Comment: I am returning the html as a string in a json object, is that a problem?  Like this `{html: "<article>...</article>"}`

Comment: is that valid HTML? article, figure etc... aren't those HTML5 elements?

Comment: I have javascript in there to add the elements to ie.

Comment: I suspect you have a missing or extra tag, or invalid nesting somewhere. To fix it, I need to reproduce it. I can't do that with the information you've given so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using HTML5 elements, I assume you're using HTML5Shiv or Modernizr to hack IE to support those elements?

If not then yes, you will definitely have issues, since IE6/7/8 will simply not recognise those tags as valid HTML.

Comment: That makes sense.  Why does it work the first time around and not when done with js?

Comment: @viatropos: if you're not using one of the HTML5 hacks in IE then you're lucky it works for any of them. You would probably find that the JS-inserted ones will work better if you insert them using DOM functions rather than innerHTML, as IE might pick up the new elements more readily that way, but I can't vouch for that. The bottom line is that IE<9 doesn't support HTML5, and while you can get away with using it in some cases, you might find other cases just don't work.

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with the html5 tags.  But why would they render fine the first time?

Comment: @viatropos: great. well done. Yes, that's the sort of tool you'd need.

Comment: +1, I wasn't aware [of this](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/#problem). I thought it was just HTML5Shiv and you're good to go.